# "Keine Arme, keine Schokolade!"

Tags: phrase

Im bekannten französischen Film "[Ziemlich beste Freunde](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1675434/)" gibt es eine Episode, wo Driss (der Pfleger) seinem querschnittsgelähmten Patienten folgenden Satz sagt:

> "Keine Arme, keine Schokolade!"

Ich verstehe das als Andeutung auf einen Witz, den ich wohl nicht kenne. Stimmt das? Was bedeutet dieser Ausdruck?

Comment: Ich kenne da diesen Contergan Witz, bekomme ihn aber nicht mehr zusammen. Essenz ist, dass das Kind in der Küche sitzt und die Mutter bittet die Keksdose vom Schrank herunterzuholen worauf sie sagt "Tja, keine Arme, keine Kekse."
Muss gute zehn Jahre her sein, dass ich den Witz das letzte mal gehört habe.

Comment: @Walter: Ich kannte den Witz nicht, aber nach kurzem Googlen sieht es in der Tat aus, als ob sich der Film darauf bezieht. Bring es doch als Antwort. Es wäre noch interessant zu wissen, wie es im französischen Original aussieht; entweder die Stelle lautet dort ganz anders oder der Witz ist auch im Französischen vorhanden (evtl. eine Frage für FL&U).

Comment: @musiKk Meine Frau, Russische Muttersprachlerin, meinte, es gibt auch einen ähnlichen Witz im Russischen. Ich, ebenso Russisch-Muttersprachler, kenne den Witz weder im Deutschen noch im Russischen.

Comment: Es gibt auch die Version mit "Tschernobilly", der am Samichlausabend am fein gedeckten Tisch seine Mutter bittet, ihm was zu geben.

Comment: Es könnte auch von dem alten amerikanischen Anti-Hippie-Imbiss-Schild 'No shoes - no shirt .. no service' inspiriert sein.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ich habe aufgrund des Kommentars von Musikk auch nochmal bei Google geschaut.

> "Mutti! Mutti! Kann ich die Kekse, die oben auf den Schrank sind, haben?" - "Natürlich mein Kind, sagt die Mutter, hol sie dir!" - "Aber Mutti, du weißt doch, ich habe keine Arme", sagt das Kind. Darauf die Mutter: "Tja! Keine Arme - keine Kekse!"
>   [Quelle](http://www.witze-datenbank.de/witze.php?katid=37)

So wie ich den Witz kenne, steht er immer in Bezug zu [Contergan](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thalidomid) beziehungsweise einem häufigen Krankheitsbild von Kindern, deren Mütter in der Schwangerschaft mit Contergan behandelt wurden; also keine oder nur stummelhafte Arme.

Inwiefern der Witz nun witzig ist, muss wohl jeder für sich entscheiden. Ich meine, dass wir den damals in der Schule auch nie allein erzählt haben, sondern nur in Verbindung mit weiteren Witzen. (So wie die Witze vom Elefanten im Kühlschrank auch nur gut werden, wenn man mehrere erzählt.)